DAY function Returned Wrong Answer

I'm trying to find a correct formula for this. I want to find the date if we add the month by 4. The answer should be September 30, 2024, but why the output is October 01, 2024? what should I add to my formula? I'm using excel 2010.
I trying to using simple date, year , month and day formula, but the result is not as expected.

So add the correct number of days - remember months have 28, 29, 30 or 31 days... And if you work with the date formatted correctly it is a serial number where adding 1 adds 1 day.

Could you try =EDATE(A1,4)? Not sure whether it is available in your version of Excel.

I don't think EOMONTH or EDATE are available by default in Excel 2010.
If you're after the last day of the month you could use day 0 of the following month:  =DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+5,0)
